# If a genderless alien used the Omnitrix, what gender would their transformation be by default?

Tags: ben-10

It was stated that by default the aliens become the same gender as the user, but what if the user didn't have a gender (such as a big chill user)? Would the aliens change gender every time they transformed? Does each transformation randomly choose one and stay that way every time it transforms, or will it always be male or female by default?

Comment: I disagree with the close votes for Opinion-based.  A valid answer would be in the form of "This was covered in season X episode Y when character A said <technological babble>".  Or even possibly, "This was never covered within the show, or by comments of the creators".

Comment: Agreed, "we don't know" is a perfectly acceptable answer; either this has happened in the show or it has not